# Decrypt / decode minecraft .dat files

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm working on a 3rd party tools for minecraft, and I been searching for a solution but I couldn't find one figure out how to decrypt .dat files. BTW using java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly stated in the link iKlsR provided, just import the minecraft server jar inside your classpath and use directly the right class to do deserialization. I guess you can open an `InputStream`, skip the header and then use an `InputObjectStream` to decorate and directly fetch the whole structure with class `com.mojang.minecraft.level.Level`.

Mind that file is compressed and that you will need to use a stream to care about that.